# Math: Giving regular expression for a language:

Tags: regex, math, regular-language

I am going over and learning regular expressions and languages. I was working through some questions about giving a regular expression to represent a specified language. The question I was a little stuck on is this:

> Come up with a regular expression that expresses the following
>   language. The alphabet of the langauge is {a,b}.
>
> The language of all strings with two consecutive a's, but no three
>   consecutive a's. (ie, "aa", "aabaa", "babaa" are in the language,
>   while "abab", "aaaab" is not).

My answer for this so far is:

```
 (b*(e+a+aa)bb*)* (aa) (bb*(e+a+aa)b*)*
```

where 'e' is the empty string and '+' functions essentially as an 'or'.

I guess what I am wondering is if my answer is correct (I believe it is), and if it can at all be simplified?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your regular expression is correct. It ensures that an `aa` exists in the string, and makes sure that `aaa` cannot exist. As for being simplest (simplest being subjective here), I would say the following is simpler:

```
(b + ab + aab)* aa (b + ba + baa)*
```

Note that you could actually derive the above from the regular expression that you have. Taking just the part before the `aa` in your regular expression, we have:

```
  (b*(e+a+aa)bb*)*
= (b*bb* + b*abb* + b*aabb*)*
= (b + ab + aab)*
```

That last step is a little bit of a jump, but it takes noticing that all those `b*`'s are redundant due to the `*` on the whole expression, and a `b` existing inside the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I think this regex matches your language as well:

```
^((ab|b)*aa(ba|b)*)*$
```